# Cannot set Carbon variable in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I want to set the value of an item to hours and minutes like this:

```
foreach ($items as $item){
    if($item->created_at->gte($begin_date) && $item->created_at->lte($end_date))
    {
        $item->created_at = $item->created_at->format('H:m');
        $sorted_items[] = $item;
    }
}
```

When I use  `dd($item->created_at->format('H:m'))` it shows the hour and minute correctly, however  when I try to set $item->created_at to the hour and minute it throws me this error:

> ```
> InvalidArgumentException in Carbon.php line 582:
> Unexpected data found.
> Data missing
> ```

Comment: is it in foreach loop ?

Comment: @rahul_m corrected

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin There is nothing more other than the name of the function and a return. The parameters are carbon dates and eloquent item.

Comment: Do you have any attribute modifiers set on your model that would convert the created_at timestamp to a Carbon instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it can't use `created_at`, this is defined in the `model.php`. If you use another attribute, something like `created_at_formatted` it should work.

```
$item->created_at_formatted = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $item->created_at)->format('H:m');
```

Laravel uses the `protected $dates;` in your Model to assign a Carbon instance, so everytime you call `$item->created_at` it will return `Carbon::parse($item->created_at)`. This can't be done cause you changed the data to incorrect values (`H:m`).

Hope this works!